# css border not showing on top of each element

Tags: html, css

I have just started with web development. I wish to keep a border on top of my every product row. Something like:

---

product image     product description

---

image    description

---

.
.

However my border is seen only on top of the first block. Kindly help.

Below is the CSS & html I have attempted

```css
.prdDes
{
    width:82%;
    float:right;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.prdDet
{
    border-top-color:#ddd;
    border-top-style:dashed;
    border-top-width:1px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="prdDet">
    <img src="images/profile/0.png" class="productimg" />
    <div class="prdDes">
        <h3>Product 1</h3>

        <p>Details about the product1. Specifications etc.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Spec1</li>
            <li>Spec2</li>
            <li>Spec3</li>
            <li>Spec4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="prdDet">
    <img src="images/profile/14.png" class="productimg" />
    <div class="prdDes">
        <h3>Product 2</h3>

        <p>Details about the product2. Specifications etc.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Spec1</li>
            <li>Spec2</li>
            <li>Spec3</li>
            <li>Spec4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
overflow: auto;
```

to `.prdDet` class style. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dvFqn/

Why is it necessary to add that style? Because `.prdDes` has float set to left it is somehow taken away from standard document flow, so it's parent `.prdDet` does not set it's height/width to its content. Setting `overflow: auto` fixes that behavior and makes `.prdDet` as high and wide as its content, what is a desired behavior in that situation.

Comment: that worked.. Though I am not sure how. It would be great if you can explain me or give me a link which explains it. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer. Hope it helped you understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

you have used `float:right;` in your prdDes class. this mean that the elements would float out of the div they are contained in unless their parent div is not floating as well. so for the `prdDet` class you must use `float:left;`... this would solve your problem.